# How to change BI Answers user's password in OBIEE12c

Tags: oracle, data-warehouse, obiee

BI Answers users manage in WebLogic 12c. I did find any options in BI answers that allow users to change his/her password. BI answers users need to communicate with WebLogic administrator to change his/her password. In OBIEE10g, there is an option in configuration file to enable change password for BI Answers. Is there any option in OBIEE12c that enable users to change password.

Answer (score 0):

It isn’t an out of the box feature. WebLogic is acting as a lightweight LDAP. See this thread for further information- https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/4477102/how-to-enable-user-to-change-the-password-for-their-account-in-obiee-12c

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).